# avdmanager hangs on "Loading local repository..." Linux

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, linux, avd-manager

Repro:

1. Headless Ubuntu `18.04 LTS` VM (kvm note enabled)
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get install -y wget openjdk-8-jre-headless libc6-i386 lib32stdc++6 python3-pip nginx unzip`
4. `sudo wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-6200805_latest.zip`
5. `sudo unzip commandlinetools-linux-6200805_latest.zip -d /opt`
6. `sudo /opt/tools/bin/sdkmanager --install --sdk_root=/opt "system-images;android-19;default;armeabi-v7a" "platform-tools" "platforms;android-19"`
7. `/opt/tools/bin/avdmanager create avd -n arm -k "system-images;android-19;default;armeabi-v7a" -f`

On step 7 in hangs with `Loading local repository...`

Notes:

- Running the avdmanager as `sudo` doesn't help, and the image need's to be created by a user anyway.
- Tried `sudo setfacl -m u:username:rwx /opt/tools/bin/avdmanager` didn't help
- setting `ANDROID_HOME=/opt` and `PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools` doesn't help
- newer version of command line tools don't help ether.

What is the problem? How can I investigate? Have I missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happened because since version (6200805) Command Line Tools should be placed inside **cmdline-tools** directory. It should be created manually in ANDROID_HOME.

Please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61176718/7100772) With the mentioned configuration everything works fine.